# jquery, creating an autoplay button

Tags: jquery

I have a link in the menu and whenever someone clicks on it, I would like it to automatically click itself on the next page and so on. Is this possible with jQuery?

I just have this code to go on,

```
$('#autoplay').click(function() {
        $('#autoplay').trigger('click');

      });
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "on the next page"?

Comment: It's a WordPress site, so that it would go to the single article and so on.

Answer (score 1):

**Using DOMstorage is piece of cake!**

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uzizal/3/edit)**  <sub>Click the button and refresh the page. Should be running by default after reading localStorage</sub>

```
$(function(){

    function myCustomFunction(){
          // Something here.....
    }

    var isAutoplay = localStorage.getItem('autoplay');

    if(isAutoplay){
        myCustomFunction();
    }

    $('#autoplay').on('click', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('autoplay', true);
        myCustomFunction();     
    });


});
```

Comment: This looks promising, but my site is saved locally, will this only work online?

Comment: @Richard : Online and locally on localhost (if you have XAMPP or WAMPP) In FF I think should work locally too.

Comment: But if it's not on a MAMP server for example, it will not work? I'm trying it now without any server and it's not working.

Comment: @Richard What, specifically, is your configuration?

Comment: Currently, the files are just pure .html files, i haven't put it into a theme for WordPress yet and it's just on my local harddrive, not on localhost.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan very cool, thank you for this, I will try to take a stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set a flag, and then call the `click` event of your link when the next event happens:

```
autoExec = false;
$('#autoplay').click(function() {
  autoExec = true;
  $('#autoplay').trigger('click');
});
```

This way, you can check if `autoExec` is set to `true`, and trigger the event.

If you want to save the value of the autoExec variable (so it can be used even if the page is reloaded), you can pass it as a POST or GET parameter.